# Overwriting an unused div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, templates

I am working on a responsive site layout where the content area for certain pages may have a right hand side info panel and others might not. I am building this site within a custom CMS that my work uses. Now, we use *Templates* where all the HTML structure is created and use macros to pull in the content that the client enters via the CMS.

Usually I would create a separate template for the pages that would use the right hand panel and a separate template for those that don't but as the client might want to add the right panels to pages that don't have them in the future, I was wondering if there is some *overwrite style* that I can add to my template so that the whole site can run on one template rather than having to add a template that has the right panel for one page and a template that doesn't for another.

My code would be something like this:

**CSS:**

```
section#maincontent {width:720px; float:left;}
aside {width:240px; float:right;}
```

**HTML:**

```
<section id="maincontent">[conetent]</section>
<aside>[right_panel]</aside>
```

Is there a piece of javascript/CSS/web magic that can overwrite the right panel div if the client decides to add/remove the right panel from a page/template so that the maincontent fills the width of the page without having to create a new template with the style added/removed?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change it to display none.

HTML
...

```
<div id="theOneToBeRemoved" onclick="remove()">
</div>
```

Javascript

```
function remove(){
   document.getElementById("theOneToBeRemoved").style.display = "none";
}
```

I will note though that you may not want to add the onclick event to the div... Maybe add a button X or close..something along those lines... So if they click into the div it doesnt accidentally close... Also, you may want to add some css transitions to your div... So that when it closes its smooth instead of so abrupt.. Looks much better

Answer (score 0):

Add a wrapper div, output the class "withoutRightPanel" when you want to "remove" right pannel, and add css rules below:

HTML

```
<div class="withoutRightPanel">
    <section id="maincontent">[conetent]</section>
    <aside class="rightPanel">[right_panel]</aside>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.withoutRightPannel .rightPanel
{
   display:none;
}
.withoutRightPannel #maincontent
{
    //Fill the gap after you hide right panel, or you can set a value by pixel
    width:100%;
}
```